# The entity type XXX is an optional dependent using table sharing without any required non shared property...' Even when the relationship is required

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

I have two entities mapped to the same table. The entities does not share navigation property, but there is one to one relationship configured.

Why I'm getting this warning:

> The entity type 'MaterialInfo2' is an optional dependent using table sharing without any required non shared property that could be used to identify whether the entity exists. If all nullable properties contain a null value in database then an object instance won't be created in the query. Add a required property to create instances with null values for other properties or mark the incoming navigation as required to always create an instance

See demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wt4BSQ

```
public partial class Material 
{
    public string MaterialCode { get; set; }
    public string Popis { get; set; }
}

public class MaterialInfo2
{
    public string MaterialCode { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Popis { get; set; }
}


public class MaterialConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Material>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Material> entity)
    {
     entity.ToTable("Material");
        entity.HasKey(e => e.MaterialCode);
        entity.Property(e => e.MaterialCode)
            .HasColumnName("MaterialCode")
            .HasMaxLength(25)
            .IsRequired();
    }
}

public class MaterialInfo2Configuration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<MaterialInfo2>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MaterialInfo2> entity)
    {

        entity.ToTable("Material");
        entity.HasKey(e => e.MaterialCode);
        entity.Property(e => e.MaterialCode).
            HasColumnName("MaterialCode")
            .HasMaxLength(25)
            .IsRequired();


        entity.HasOne<Material>()
           .WithOne()
           .HasForeignKey<MaterialInfo2>(e => e.MaterialCode)
           .HasPrincipalKey<Material>(e => e.MaterialCode)
           .IsRequired(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: That relationship makes absolutely no sense... You can have multiple entities defined for the same tables in cases where you use Table-per-Hierarchy inheritance with a discriminator, however I don't see anything like that in the relationship you are creating. How can you have a 1 to 1 relationship in the same table on the same column??

Comment: EF Core requires to define one to one relationship between entities mapped to the same table. I don't want inheritance, just each entity with it's own set of columns - it's called table splitting I think

Answer (score 0):

The warning is to say that if all of the properties used by the dependent entity —i.e., `MaterialInfo2`— are `NULL` in the database no instance will be created for that dependent entity when querying that row.

In this case as there's no navigation property involved, I think we can ignore the warning (I got here because of the same `WRN`).

From the [Advanced table mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/table-splitting#optional-dependent-entity):

> If all of the columns used by a dependent entity are NULL in the database, then no instance for it will be created when queried. This allows modeling an optional dependent entity, where the relationship property on the principal would be null. Note that this would also happen if all of the dependent's properties are optional and set to null, which might not be expected.
>
> However, the additional check can impact query performance. In addition, if the dependent entity type has dependents of its own, then determining whether an instance should be created becomes non-trivial. To avoid these issues the dependent entity type can be marked as required, see Required one-to-one dependents for more information.

If a navigation property does exist I think the way we have to make force an instance creation for the dependent entity is to do something like:

```cs
// In MaterialConfiguration
builder
    .HasOne(m => m.Material2Nav)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<Material2>(m => m.MaterialCode);
builder.Navigation(m => m.Material2Nav).IsRequired();
```

Comment: Hopefully I didn't get this wrong :)